# Reference request- Darboux cubic of a triangle

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Hi everyone on Math Stackexchange,

I'm recently interested in the geometry of a triangle, and my studies now seems to require some knowledge on cubic curves related to a triangle, in particular the Darboux cubic. I could not find any useful reference of its properties' **proofs** (e.g. the de Longchamps points is its *pivot*, which means any point on the curve is collinear with its isogonal conjugate with respect to the reference triangle and the de Longchamps point of the reference triangle). Can any one please tell me where I can find discussions on the Darboux cubic related to a triangle please? Thank you.

Wilson Zhao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the de [Longchamps point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deLongchampsPoint.html) $L$ is the pivot of the [Darboux cubic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DarbouxCubic.html) just follows from the fact that $L$ has trilinear coordinates:
$$ L:[\cos A-\cos B\cos C;\cos B-\cos A\cos C;\cos C-\cos A\cos B]$$
and a point with trilinear coordinates $[\alpha;\beta;\gamma]$ lies on the Darboux cubic iff:
$$ \sum_{cyc}(\cos A-\cos B\cos C)\alpha(\beta^2-\gamma^2)=0.$$
Good references for triangle cubics are [Forum Geometricorum](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/) and the Hyacinthos mailing list.

Comment: This is wonderful but can you please elaborate a little bit on how the conclusion follows from the trilinear coordinate equations? Thanks

Comment: @WilsonofGordon: it is a general fact that the pivot of a cubic with equation $$\sum_{cyc} K_A\alpha(\beta^2-\gamma^2)=0$$ is the point $[K_A;K_B;K_C]$. Are you aware of the fact that the isogonal conjugate of $[K_A;K_B;K_C]$ is just $[K_A^{-1};K_B^{-1};K_C^{-1}]$?

Comment: Right I was not aware of that fact, in actuality. Given that now I can see the desired conclusion follows from a simple evaluation of determinant. Thanks.